# Google Mock: object of abstract class type "xyz" is not allowed?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

Using Visual Studio 2010 C++ with GMock. Trying to create a stub object for a third party class that is used by my classes but I'm getting the following error:

> Error: object of abstract class type
>   "ThirdPartyClassFake " is not allowed.

The third party class is defined like:

```
namespace ThirdPartyNamespace
{

class __declspec(novtable) ThirdPartyClass : public ThirdPartyBaseClass
{
public:
    virtual bool Hello() const = 0;
    virtual bool Goodbye() const = 0;
};

}
```

I created a mock of this:

```
namespace ThirdPartyNamespace {

class ThirdPartyClassFake : public ThirdPartyClass {
 public:
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(Hello, bool());
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(Goodbye, bool());
};
}
```

Now in my test I'm trying to do:

```
TEST(MyService, WhenCalled_DoesTheRightThingTM) {

    // Arrange
    ThirdPartyClassFake stub;

    // Act
    ...

    // Assert
    ...
}
```

The error is on the "ThirdPartyClassFake stub;" line.  Why am I getting this error and how can I successfully create a mock/stub object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically the problem was that although I implemented `ThirdPartyClass`'s virtual methods in my mock object, I neglected to implement `ThirdPartyBaseClass`'s virtual methods.  This was causing the error.  Once I added `MOCK_METHOD` calls for those methods the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

Class `ThirdPartyClass` is an abstract class ( two pure virtual member functions ). Any class that derives from it **must** override/implement the virtual methods.

Comment: Ok makes sense, but I thought that is what my google mock class is doing.  Hold on I'm wondering if the parent class, ThirdPartyBaseClass
, has some virtual methods that I might need to implement?